# How can I tp a player to an entity without locking my vision

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I did a lot of testing but I can't find a way to `/tp` a player to an entity ( with the `/fill` clock ) without having all the time my vision locked. Every time I teleport to the entity I want, I can't move my head because it teleports me again. How can I teleport constantly to a entity and face where I want freely.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely adding the 2 unnecessary arguments to the tp command, the `y-rot` and `x-rot`, which goes at the end of the command.

It would be better if you had posted the command, but this is what your command souls look like

```
/tp @p @e[...]
```

Or if you use a flat x y z

```
/tp x y z
```

Do not add the last 2 numbers if you already have a x y z

Comment: When teleporting an entity to another entity, the teleported entity will inherit the rotation of the target. He is asking how to teleport an entity to another entity without inheriting the rotation.